# URI parse Kotlin for image seems to be not working

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, uri

I'm making an app with Android Studio and I managed to let the user open the gallery and get the URI from the picture. The URI is then used to set the background in the XML like this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    val uri = data?.data
    settings_profile_image.setImageURI(uri)
    profile_img_drawer.setImageURI(uri)
```

But I want to save the image so if the user closes the app and re-opens it, the picture is showed again. So I've added this to the onActivityResult:

```
Prefs(this).changeProfileUri(uri = uri.toString())
```

And in **Prefs.kt**:

```
fun changeProfileUri(uri: String) {
    editor.putString("profileImgUri", uri)
    editor.apply()
}

fun changeProfileUri(uri: String) {
    editor.putString("profileImgUri", uri)
    editor.apply()
}
```

And when I want to retrieve the image:

```
val profileImgUriSaved = Prefs(this).getProfileImgUri()
val profileImgUri = Uri.parse(profileImgUriSaved)
settings_profile_image.setImageURI(profileImgUri)
```

But it doesn't work. So does anyone has an idea why?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What is the behavior? If "it doesn't work" means "I cannot load the image", bear in mind that you may have no rights to view that image from anything other than the activity instance that received the `Uri` in `onActivityResult()`. For something like a profile, you should make a copy of the image in your own app's portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and use that local copy going forward.

Comment: it doesn't work does mean that the image doesn't load. The image simply doesn't show up. I retrieve the image-URI in the same activity as `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Have you inspected `profileImgUri`? Is it valid?

Comment: How could I do that?